# Why is dependency repeated many times in Webpack artifact?

Tags: javascript, webpack, styled-components, atlaskit

I have a multi-entry point webpack build and I am working on optimizing artifact size for production. `webpack-bundle-analyzer` produced the following picture:

[image]

It's obvious that the [AtlasKit](https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/) dependencies make up a huge chunk of the total artifact size. Specifically, I see that `styled-components.es.js` is repeated many times. More so, this same dependency is is also present in `vendor.js` which itself is shared among all other packages.

Can anyone explain why `styled-components.es.js` is repeated all over and why it cannot be shared via single dependency in `vendor.js`? Is there anything I can do to remove duplicates and only depend on the single `styled-components.es.js` dependency in `vendor.js`?

I found it a bit strange that AtlasKit dependencies have a nested `node_modules` folder that is included in the package. Why is `dist` not enough? Maybe that's part of the reason why `styled-components.es.js` cannot be shared via `vendor.js`?

[image]

I tried to exclude the dependency manually via webpack's IgnorePlugin (similar to `moment.js` locales) but failed so far to do so.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this? Having the same problem, thought I was just bad at webpack but it seems something is configured strangely with @atlaskit

Comment: @MitchLillie unfortunately I didn't and I stopped investing more time on this.  However, I if ever find some time again I would like to investigate this more. I still believe there should be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know exactly what fixed the issue, I just noticed that the latest release of Atlaskit now works with tree-shaking. I now get minimal artifacts with everything shared from Atlaskit in a big vendor.js.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to consolidate a dependency from multiple chunks into a common chunk: For this I would recommend looking into [`webpack.CommonsChunkPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/).

Of particular interest is the `minChunks` property you can pass to the plugin:

> minChunks: number|Infinity|function(module, count) -> boolean,
>     // The minimum number of chunks which need to contain a module before it's moved into the commons chunk.
>     // The number must be greater than or equal 2 and lower than or equal to the number of chunks.
>     // Passing `Infinity` just creates the commons chunk, but moves no modules into it.
>     // By providing a `function` you can add custom logic. (Defaults to the number of chunks)

I advise trying to add this plugin to your Webpack config:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  children: true,
  async: true,
  minChunks: 3
})
```

This usage is described further in ["Extra async commons chunk"](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#extra-async-commons-chunk).

If you are interested in seeing the amount of code shared between your chunks, consider trying [`samccone/bundle-buddy`](https://github.com/samccone/bundle-buddy) for Webpack as well.

If you are already using `CommonsChunkPlugin`, I would need to see your Webpack config to provide further information.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your reply. I am already using CommonsChunkPlugin, that's how I get `vendor.js`. You can see my Webpack config here: https://pastebin.com/vgiQrPqs

Comment: Thanks for posting your config. I suspect you are not getting real tree-shaking out of `@atlaskit` because you are importing the already transpiled code. It doesn't look like `@atlaskit` supports the `"module"` field which would allow you to consume it as an ES Module.

Atlassian Kit seems to ship with a key `"ak:webpack:raw": "src/index.jsx"` which points to their raw source code. You could include from this entry point using a process described in [`this 2ality post`](http://2ality.com/2017/06/pkg-esnext.html#package-users).

They should be using the "module" field, not `ak:webpack:raw`